# Редактировать JSON с помощью Node.js

Tags: javascript, json

хотел спросить, тех кто изучает/знает node.js, достаточно, чтобы объяснить, как редактировать, удалять и/или дублировать JSON файл. Недавно, мне понадобилось добавлять и обновлять данные в JSON файле, и так-как я уже использовал Electron, у меня уже была Node.js, можете сказать, как с помощью JS выполнить редактирование JSON файла? Если это вомзожно, я бы хотел обойтись без ответов, которые просто кидают ссылку со статей на то, как работает JSON, Node.js и прочее, мне нужна по возможности уже готовая функция, но если это будет трудно, то я готов почитать и статью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Редактировать JSON-файлы напрямую не имеет особого смысла и чревато ошибками. Обычно порядок такой:

- читаете содержимое файла и получаете JSON-строку
- парсите JSON-строку в объект или другой тип данных
- изменяете этот объект обычными средствами JS
- сериализируете объект в JSON-строку
- записываете JSON-строку в тот же файл, тем самым изменяя его.

Например, у нас есть файл `test.json`:

```json
{"key1":"value1"}
```

Изменяем его в соответствии с описанным порядком:

```js
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';

const json1 = readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');

const object = JSON.parse(json1);
object.key2 = 'value2';

const json2 = JSON.stringify(object);
writeFileSync('test.json', json2);
```

Получаем изменённый файл `test.json`:

```json
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это и правда помогло. Мне нужно было изменять в JSON токены, так-как я пишу бота, и не знал как это реализовать, Вы мне очень помогли, ещё раз спасибо.